# Meteor enter press not working on submitting a form

Tags: forms, meteor, submit

I'm having a problem submitting a form in meteor. I'm following the tutorial from meteor, seen in other places, but my keypress event simply doesn't work. I have this code in my html file:

```html
{{> novasessao}}

<template name="novasessao">
    <form class="nova-sessao">
        <div class="caixaDadosCliente dadosCliente no-padding">
            <label>Nome</label>
            <input class="inputs" type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Introduza o seu nome" />
            <label>Idade(anos)</label>
            <input type="text" name="idade" placeholder="Introduza a dua idade" />
            <label>Género</label>
            <input type="text" name="genero" placeholder="Introduza o seu sexo" />
            <label>Sessão #</label>
            <input type="text" name="sessao" placeholder="Introduza o número de sessão" />
            <label>Data</label>
            <input type="date" name="data" placeholder="Introduza a data" />
            <label>Quem preenche o formulário?</label>
            <input type="text" name="quemPreenche" placeholder="Introduza quem está a preencher o questionário" /> 
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

and this code on the associated js file

```js
Template.novasessao.events({
  'submit form': function(event,template){
      console.log('reached novasessao.submit form');
      console.log(event.target.nome.value);
      event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

But have no console output. Nothing happens, nor errors.

Could you please help me do some debug..

Thanks!

Comment: Have you imported html file (the one in which you defined the template), on top of your js file in which you define the event ?

Comment: Yes, It's imported. Tested on the top of js files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still submit this form without a submit button (if that's a still a requirement).

Try this:

```js
'keypress form.nova-sessao': function (event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const target = event.currentTarget;
        const nome = target.nome.value;
        const idade = target.idade.value;

        console.log('NOME', nome);
        console.log('IDADE', idade);
        $(event.target).submit();
        console.log('form submitted');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jeremiah. This actually prints 'form submitted' but when i try to get my input values, and insert them  there is an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at Object.keypressFormNovaSessao`.  I'm doing like this: `  
   const target = event.target;
  const nome = target.nome.value;
  const idade = target.idade.value;
  ....

  Clientes.insert({
  nome,
  idade,
  });`

Comment: You're looking for `event.currentTarget`. `event.target` refers to the DOM element that the user was focused on when the `keypress` event fired. `event.currentTarget` refers to the DOM element that is the subject of the event itself. Example: If you press enter while in the `nome` input, `event.currentTarget` would be `form.nova-sessao` while `event.target` would be `input[name='nome']`. [Here's a good illustration of this concept](http://joequery.me/code/event-target-vs-event-currenttarget-30-seconds/). If this solves your problem, don't forget to accept the answer :).

Comment: Hi Jeremiah, thank you, it's working...now I have to see how to submit only in the last field, but I still have a lot to learn. Thank you for the explanation about the target and currentTarget :-)

Answer (score 0):

Events works with css selectors,Change your code to below :

```
Template.novasessao.events({
  'submit .nova-sessao': function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log(event);

}
});
```

Comment: @EvaOliveiraGonçalves it should work, I have edited the answer, Try it.

Comment: It isn't superB :( is there any other way to show you my whole code? any meteor, codepen, jsFiddle like platform?

Comment: you can make a fiddle or gist or any other upload , send to me.